# How to output ALL of the settings an Emacs version comes by default with as text to see where the differences between the versions are?

Tags: init-file, customization

The Title already tells what the question is about.

The purpose of the answer to this question would be to become able to find out which default values differ between the versions 27.1 and 28.2 of Emacs in order to set them explicit in the initialization file achieving as consequence the effect that the layout of the windows for both versions which currently looks like this:

[image]

will become the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `emacs -q` to launch Emacs, then use `M-x ielm` and issue:

```lisp
(defun customizable-variable-value-pairs (&rest other-features)
  "Print all the bound customizable variables from the loaded packages and C source code, with their default values.

For those unloaded packages, you can pass them as the arguments so that the bound customizable variables from them will also be printed."
  (mapcar (lambda (feature)
            (require feature)) other-features)
  (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
              (when (and
                     (custom-variable-p symbol)
                     (boundp symbol))
                (print (format "%s"
                               (cons symbol (symbol-value symbol))))))))
```

Here's an example:

```lisp
(customizable-variable-value-pairs 'whitespace 'tramp)
```

PS: It is a long list.

> to see where the differences between the versions are?

You can search, say `"28.1"`, in the symbol's docstring to see whether that symbol's default value was changed in version 28.1, or that symbol was introduced in version 28.1, etc.

---

According to your question description, `C-h n` may be another choice:

> `C-h n` runs the command `view-emacs-news`
>
> ...
>
> Display info on **recent changes** to Emacs.
> With argument, display info only for the selected version.

That's all you want.

For example, if you want to see the changes about *themes*, use `C-s theme` in the buffer `NEW`:

> ** New themes 'modus-vivendi' and 'modus-operandi'.

Comment: Yeah ... I have already seen that 28.2 has the `modus-vivendi-theme`, `modus-operandi-theme` and the `modus-themes` which is around a half MByte large. What is `modus-themes`? Each theme in Emacs should end with -theme.el, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry ... I can't follow ... I have started emacs with `emacs -q` getting the splash window content. No sign of *ielm* in the buffer list, nor have I an idea how to evaluate the provided code.

Comment: @Claudio: use `M-x ielm`. My mistake. I forgot to mention it

Comment: @Claudio: A `*-theme.el` usually contains a `(provide-theme ...)`, but `modus-themes.el` does not. Instead, it contains a `(provide 'modus-themes)`. I guess that `modus-themes.el` provides some utilities for `modus-*-theme.el` (for example, `modus-vivendi-theme.el` contains a `(require 'modus-themes)`) so users will find easy to create their own `modus-*-theme.el`, i don't know

Comment: OK ... I should be aware of ielm as the interactive emacs lisp interpreter to use for evaluating code. You couldn't know. Now I have saved the buffer as a file. I am aware already of some elisp basics: t is something like True nil is something like False ' prevents evaluation, (method param1ofMethod param2ofMethod). What does the DOT ',' mean for example in "(make-pointer-invisible . t)"?

Comment: @Claudio: (Well, that should be another question ...) <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html#Dotted-Pair-Notation> will answer your question mentioned in your comment. BTW, if you are new to Elisp or Common Lisp, I recommend you read <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html> (That's how I got started.); you can also read it in your Emacs (use `C-h i m intro <RET>`). Hope it will help you.

Comment: I have searched through the entire output but was not able to find a line with setting a value to 80. I see two options explaining it:1. there are not all of the options there in the output 2. I am still missing some understanding expecting to find which name is getting assigned to 80. Maybe is 80 default when the elisp name isn't there? So searching for it in the output does not make sense?

Comment: @Claudio: emmm ... You hope to find a variable whose value is 80?  What is this variable about?

Comment: It sets the column number from which the line starts to be considered too long and become as such highlighted. In order to set this value to 73. In between I know that `(setq-default  whitespace-line-column 73)` does the job in emacs 29. In emacs 27 it does not work - probably because emacs 27  it runs into an error loading ~/.emacs and does not load it.

Comment: @Claudio: The answer will output all the bound customizable variables of the loaded packages.  If the certain variable you want doesn't appear in the output, probably because its package hasn't been loaded. You need to `(require 'xxx)` first.

Comment: I have just checked it out again. The whitespace-line-column is not mentioned at all in the output. So there is some output - most without the related values, but nor really complete ...

Comment: I have accepted your answer to come here to an end - won't work on it next days. If I would know a better way to query the initial settings I will come back here with details. The claim that the code prints all customizable settings seems to be not true.

Comment: If I need to know where to look by passing a name to require ... I don't need the list to find out where a value is set.

Comment: The question is: are the packages silently loaded by the binary without reflecting it in the elisp code available in the user interface to query? Best I ask a question about it ...

Comment: @Claudio: "are the packages silently loaded by the binary without reflecting it in the elisp code available in the user interface to query?" --- the value of `features` may be helpful to you